# How to move my cancel button method into a seperate class

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2008

This is a "Good Programing" question to avoid the need of me cutting and pasting code.  A programming mentor once said to me if you are cutting and pasting code then you are probably doing it wrong.
I have a C# windows forms application that has half a dozen data entry screens.  I am implementing functionality to confirm the discarding of changes if the user presses the cancel button when the form has changes made to its data entry controls. I don't want to cut and paste this code into every form's button_Cancel_Click method.

I have already moved the "Are You Sure" question into a separate class but if I try and close the form from another class the compiler complains about not knowing what the "this" in "this.Close()" is referring to.

Or is this as good as it gets and I should just duplicate the code?
Thanks in advance
David

```
    private void buttonCancel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Check and warn users of changes to the data before close.
        if (dataChanged)
        {
            bool discardChanges = CancelForm.AreYouSure();
            if (discardChanges)
            {
                this.Close();
            }
        }
        else
        {
            this.Close();
        }
    }
```

Comment: I suggest using an *abstract* base class inherited from `Form` with `Cancel` button, `buttonCancel_Click method`, `DataChanged` property etc. When implementing a form just inherit from the base class.

Comment: I would suggest using either a function that handles the logic: '            if (ValidateChangesMade(dataChanged)) {
                this.Close();
            }
' or adding the logic to the CancelForm class: `            if (CancelForm.ValidateChangesMade(dataChanged)) {
                this.Close();
            }`

Comment: Although it really is up to you, what I usually do is follow the MVC logic as much as possible so if you ever need to make changes or even convert your program to a web app, you just change the interface. Following this logic I would suggest to keep this method in each form separately instead of puting in another class since it affects the interface of your program only and moving it to another class would tightly couple that class to your interface.

Answer (score 0):

I decided to follow Kostas Balis advise, so I basically copied and pasted my code as is to each of the forms with a cancel button.  I was hoping to learn something new but it seems this may not have been the best place/time to learn it.

From Dimitry "Using an abstract base class inherited from form...." used to many terms that I don't fully understand.  I know, things I need to learn.

FSDaniel's option looks interesting.  I never thought of passing this.Close as a variable to my cancel form class.  This is probably closest to what I was originally thinking of doing.

In the end I decided to keep it simple and understandable as possible because who knows it may be me that is trying to understand it in years to come. :)

P.S. The program I'm writing is replacing a program I wrote 15 years ago using Access 97 and it is still going in production :)

Thanks for your thoughts and comments.

David